# DataTable Sorting - Sorting by a click on the header

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables, datatables-1.10

I have created this datatable:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    const table1 = $('#songs').DataTable({
      searching: false,
      paging: false
    });
  });
</script>
```

but when I click on the header nothing happens

http://45.79.248.19:8080/songs

Comment: Please make a reproducible example.

Comment: Please create a reproducible example using a tools such as [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), or similar. (When I run the code you have provided in the question, it works correctly - there are no problems with sorting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code:

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <th>BPM</th>
    <th>ARTIST</th>
    <th>ALBUM</th>
    <th>LABEL</th>
    <th>SONG</th>
  </tr>
  ...
```

You are putting your `th` inside `tbody`. That's the problem. You need to put your `th` in `thead` tag because it allows DataTables to know what should be used for the column headers and the click-to-order controls.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bw3pz82u/)

More info [here](https://datatables.net/manual/installation#HTML).